# How to obtain a Google oauth2 refresh token?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-oauth

The following code uses the Google oauth2 mechanism to sign in a user.  We need to process updates to the user's calendar while the user is offline, so we ultimately need the 'refresh token'.  Does the result from grantOfflineAccess() return the refresh token (below, I can see that response.code holds a value that might be the refresh token)?

How can I get a refresh token that can be used (server side) to create new access keys for offline access to a user's Google calendar?

[image]

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function handleClientLoad() {
        gapi.load('client:auth2', initClient);
    }

    function initClient() {
        gapi.client.init({
            apiKey: 'MY_API_KEY',
            clientId: 'MY_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com',
            discoveryDocs: ['https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/calendar/v3/rest'],
            scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'
        }).then(function () {
            var GoogleAuth = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
            GoogleAuth.signIn();
            GoogleAuth.grantOfflineAccess().then(function (response) {
                var refresh_token = response.code;
            });
        });
    }

</script>

<script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"
        onload="this.onload=function(){};handleClientLoad()"
        onreadystatechange="if (this.readyState === 'complete') this.onload()">
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a reason why you are having a problem getting a *refresh token* out of JavaScript. That reason being that it's not possible.

JavaScript is a *client side* programming language, for it to work you would have to have your client id and client secret embedded in the code along with the *refresh token*. This would be visible to anyone who did a view source on the web page.

I think you realize why that's probably a bad idea. The main issue is that `gapi` won't return it the library just doesn't have that ability (*not that I have tried in raw JavaScript to see if the OAuth server would return it if I asked nicely*).

You will need to switch to some *server side* language. I have heard that this can be done with Node.js, but haven't tried myself. And Java, PHP, Python are all valid options too.

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42594821/google-api-offline-access-to-user-data), you should include the specific [scopes](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes#calendarv3) in your requests. Your client configuration should have `$client->setAccessType("offline");` and `$client->setApprovalPrompt("force");`.

> After allowing access, you will be returned an access code that you can exchange for an access token. The access token returned is the one you need to save in a database. Later on, if the user needs to use the calendar service, you simply use the access token you already saved.

Here's a sample code:

> ```
> /*
>  * @$accessToken - json encoded array (access token saved to database)
> */
>
> $client = new Google_Client();
> $client->setAuthConfig("client_secret.json");
> $client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar");
>
> $_SESSION["access_token"] = json_decode($accessToken, true);
>
> $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
> $service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);
>
> //REST OF THE PROCESS HERE
> ```

Comment: I think this is for server side PHP.  I need to have the user authenticate from a browser that runs our application, and then SERVER SIDE update the user's calendar while the user is offline from our app.